# A bug in the SSAS browser (hierarchy, dimension)

Tags: ssas, hierarchy, dimension

I have a user defined hierarchy:

A > B

The dimension key is a composition key of A and B.

Now if i browse the cube and use hierarchy *as a filter*, it will not work (showing nothing in the measures).

But if i use hierarchy *as row field*, it will work, showing the hierarchy members nicely .

Any ideas?

.

Comment: Is it maybe a calculated measure what you are trying to show? What is the operator you are using for the comparison in the filter? Do the values of the hierarchy levels appear in the filter expression field?

Comment: Could you add some sample code to explain what you mean? Are you creating the query using a GUI tool, or writing MDX?

Comment: I'm using the cube browser in the GUI (and tried also pivot table in Excel).
I'm not using any calculated measures. The cube with dimension process fine.

Answer (score 0):

The GUI cube browser in SSMS and in the SSRS Query Editor write MDX queries for you. To get very far, you should start to learn the basics of MDX.

If you put a dimension on the X axis and then, maybe, uncheck a few of the items, the generated MDX will just list those items in the Select clause.

```
select 
{[Measures].[Measure1]} on 0,
{[A].&[ID1], [A].&[ID2], [A].&[ID3]} on 1
From mycube
```

If you put a dimension in the filter area immediately above the grid, it will add the filter to the WHERE clause - so you won't see the dimension members, but you will see the measures. You will still need to add something to either the X or Y axis to get any results

```
select 
From mycube
Where {[A].&[ID1], [A].&[ID2], [A].&[ID3]}
```

Finally. if you use the filter fields at the top of the window, the autogenerated MDX will create a subcube. Again, you will still have to specify something to show up on at least one axis to get something to measure over.

```
Select 
From 
( Select {[A].&[ID1], [A].&[ID2], [A].&[ID3]} on 0 From mycube)
```

Comment: If i use dimension member that is not in the fact table, maybe this will show as empty ?

Comment: The GUI tool shouldn't let you use a dimension that isn't linked to the Fact table. If you filter down to a dimension member that isn't associated with any fact data, you will get a NULL/Empty value.

Answer (score 0):

Found out what it was.

Dimension is made from another table which has more members than the table from which measure is made. (aprrox 50% more dimension members than there are measure members)

So it shows many empty rows when using the dimension as filter, working as designed, and it will not fail when processing the cube, because all the measure keys are found in the dimension.